# How to solve Cyclic Dependency

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, service-layer

```
public class NotificationService: INotificationService{

    private ILogService _logService;

    public NotificationService(ILogService logService){

        _logService = logService;

    }

}


public class LogService: ILogService{

    private INotificationService _notificationService;

    public LogService(INotificationService notificationService){

    _notificationService = notificationService;

    }

}
```

I came into a situation where two classes depends on each other. I am using Ninject.

```
Bind<INotificationService>().To<NotificationService>();
Bind<ILogService>().To<LogService>();
```

The codes above are causing Cyclic Dependency.
What is the proper way to solve this? Please share some codes.

Comment: Just a quick question: How do you work with these classes without any DI container?

Comment: @MaKCbIMKo raises a *very* important question that should try to answer.

Comment: @MaKCbIMKo I am using Ninject IoC Container

Comment: I mean, if you have a cyclic dependencies, it means that you have problem with design of your software.

Answer (score 3):

A cyclic dependency is an indication of a design or modeling problem in your software. Although you can construct your object graph by using property injection, you will ignore the root cause and add another problem: property injection causes [Temporal Coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/).

Instead, the solution is to look at the design closely. Often you will find that there is a third 'hidden' service that needs to be abstracted. Both services can depend on this new service.

Since your question is quite high-level with just the interface names and the dependencies between the components, it's hard to be specific, but here's an possible solution:

```
public class Logger : ILogger { }

public class NotificationService : INotificationService{
    private ILogger _logger;

    public NotificationService(ILogger logger){
        _logger = logger;
    }
}

public class LogService : ILogService {
    private ILogger _logger;

    public LogService(ILogger logger){
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case, the Logger class will also depends on NotificationService and LogService which will create another cyclic dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Use property injection for one (or both) of the classes:
[Cyclic dependency with ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511547/cyclic-dependency-with-ninject)

```
public class NotificationService: INotificationService{

    ILogService LogService { set; }
}


public class LogService: ILogService{

    private INotificationService _notificationService;

    public LogService(INotificationService notificationService){
    {
        notificationService.LogService = this;
    }
}
```