# use ninject in both service creates cyclical dependency in c#

Tags: c#, web-services, dependency-injection, ninject

I have 2 services as you can see with these constructors :

```
public ReceptionService(DataContext ctx, IPaymentService PaymentService, IReceptionHistoryService ReceptionHistoryService, ITestService TestService, ITestRepository TestRepository ,IReferredRepository ReferredRepository, IAutomotiveRepository AutomotiveRepository,IReceptionRepository ReceptionRepository,IReferredService ReferredService,IAutomotiveService AutomotiveService)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
        _automotiveRepository = AutomotiveRepository;
        _referredRepository = ReferredRepository;
        _receptionRepository = ReceptionRepository;
        _referredService = ReferredService;
        _automotiveService = AutomotiveService;
        _testService = TestService;
        _receptionHistoryService = ReceptionHistoryService;
        _paymentService = PaymentService;
    }
```

An another one :

```
 public TestService(DataContext ctx, IReceptionService ReceptionService ,IParameterService ParameterService, ILineService LineService, ITestRepository TestRepository, IReceptionHistoryService ReceptionHistoryService
        , IReceptionHistoryRepository ReceptionHistoryRepository)
    {
        _TestRepository = TestRepository;
        _parameterService = ParameterService;
        _receptionHistoryRepository = ReceptionHistoryRepository;
        _receptionHistoryService = ReceptionHistoryService;
        _lineService = LineService;
        _ctx = ctx;
    }
```

With these constructors everything works fine but when i add the `ReceptionService` to the `TestService` like this :

```
 public TestService(DataContext ctx, IReceptionService ReceptionService ,IParameterService ParameterService, ILineService LineService, ITestRepository TestRepository, IReceptionHistoryService ReceptionHistoryService
        , IReceptionHistoryRepository ReceptionHistoryRepository)
    {
        _TestRepository = TestRepository;
        _parameterService = ParameterService;
        _receptionHistoryRepository = ReceptionHistoryRepository;
        _receptionHistoryService = ReceptionHistoryService;
        _lineService = LineService;
        _ReceptionService = ReceptionService;
        _ctx = ctx;
    }
```

I get this error :

```
Error activating IReceptionService using binding from IReceptionService to ReceptionService
A cyclical dependency was detected between the constructors of two services.

Activation path:
 5) Injection of dependency IReceptionService into parameter ReceptionService of constructor of type TestService
 4) Injection of dependency ITestService into parameter TestService of constructor of type ReceptionService
 3) Injection of dependency IReceptionService into parameter ReceptionService of constructor of type TestService
 2) Injection of dependency TestService into parameter instance of constructor of type NinjectIISHostingServiceHost{TestService}
 1) Request for NinjectIISHostingServiceHost{TestService}

Suggestions:
 1) Ensure that you have not declared a dependency for IReceptionService on any implementations of the service.
 2) Consider combining the services into a single one to remove the cycle.
 3) Use property injection instead of constructor injection, and implement IInitializable
    if you need initialization logic to be run after property values have been injected.
```

Comment: You are injection ITestService into ReceptionService and IReceptionService into TestService. I am not surprised that doesn't work. I'm not sure what your question is, but if it is along the lines of "how to get rid of this error?", the answer is along the lines of "don't make A dependant on B if B is dependant on A".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cyclic dependency with ninject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511547/cyclic-dependency-with-ninject)

Comment: @oerkelens i need the reception service inside testservice

Comment: If you need the reception service inside the test service, then fine, use it. But if you _also_ need the test service inside the reception service, something is wrong and you need to rethink your application architecture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My experience is that cyclic dependencies are typically caused by [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (SRP) violations. In other words, one or multiple of the classes that are part of the cycle have too many responsibilities.

The two classes in question both have a lot of dependencies. This is a code smell called [Constructor Over-Injection](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/constructor-over-injection-smell-ndash-follow-up/) and Constructor Over-Injection is an indication as well of a SRP violation.

In other words: your classes violate SRP and the solution is to split them into multiple smaller, more fine-grained components. This not only solves the SRP (and thus the maintainability problem that this causes), but the cyclic dependency problem as well.